# javascript function make a full postback in an update panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I call the following javascript function in an update panel which **refresh** my page although it is in an update panel!!

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function get_emp_num(source, eventArgs) {
        var txt_emp_num = "<%= txt_RequestEmpNum.ClientID %>";
        document.getElementById(txt_emp_num).value = eventArgs.get_value();
        __doPostBack("<%=txt_RequestEmpNum.ClientID %>");
    }

    function get_person_num(source, eventArgs) {
        var txt_person_num = "<%= txt_RequestPersonNum.ClientID %>";
        document.getElementById(txt_person_num).value = eventArgs.get_value();
        __doPostBack("<%=txt_RequestPersonNum.ClientID %>");
    }

</script>
```

---

I don't want this script to change the partial post back behavior  of my update panel .how to do that ?

Comment: You used `c#` tag because..?

Comment: Are you saying you don't want to refresh the page? I don't understand..

Comment: yeah i don't want this script to refresh my whole page

Comment: @SonerGönül Asp.net may refer to VB.NET, C#, etc. I think C# tag is useful here, to provide code sample in correct language

Comment: can you show us the updatepanel html?

Comment: `<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
.....
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>`

Comment: @Gmoliv I don't think so. This is a javascript question. I can't see any reason to use `c#` tag for this question.

Comment: Have you tried registering your javascript function with the ScriptManager on your page? If that doesn't work then I'd go with using jQuery and AJAX.

Comment: You need to provide more code, I test this code and works ok with my html, so without more code can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

What is your postback control and is it setup as an async trigger on the update panel?  Based on the code you posted, I suspect that txt_RequestEmpNum and txt_RequestPersonNum are text boxes. Those controls don't natively support postbacks.  What you need is a hidden button on the page that your javascript will "click" to send the postback.  Something like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_RequestEmpNum" runat="server" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_RequestPersonNum" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<div style="display: none;">
    <asp:Button id="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
</div>

<script>
    function get_emp_num(source, eventArgs) {
        // I am unsure what your intent was with the code here so I removed it
        __doPostBack("<%=Button1.UniqueID %>", "");
    }

    function get_person_num(source, eventArgs) {
        // I am unsure what your intent was with the code here so I removed it
        __doPostBack("<%=Button1.UniqueID %>", "");
    }

    function refresh_using_jquery() {
        __doPostBack($('#<%=Button1.ClientID %>').attr('name'), '');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @just_name, sorry about that, it was late and I used the wrong identifier. __doPostBack expects the name attribute of the button, not the id. UniqueID should return that value. I'm adding another option you can use if you have jquery on the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to not do a full page postback then you'll want to implement a solution that uses AJAX. I would go with using jQuery because it makes using AJAX somewhat easier (in my opinion, anyway).